# Android Help on Creating multiple copies of same bitmap using canvas on a surface view

Tags: android, android-widget

i want to create same copy of a bitmap image on draw method. i am using surface veiw and extending

```
public  class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Bitmap redCoin1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.red);
```

how do i copy the same redcoin1 . i need 18 copies on screan. how do i go ahead with it.

Regards
Zaheer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't decode bitmaps in `onDraw()`! Your performance will fall through the floor and you may run out of memory.

Decode the bitmap in your constructor and use [`Canvas.drawBitmap()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) in `onDraw()` to draw it wherever it's needed, as many times as you want.